# Find $\int \frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln x}{x^2+x} \, dx$.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

It has been a week that I am practicing integral, and I am stuck at this simple problem:

> $$\int \frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln x}{x^2+x} \, dx$$

Comment: I think that you meant this fraction. Check. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Ive tried splitting the fraction, like : ln(x+1)/x(x+1) - lnx/x(x+1), but it doesnt seem to be the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Set $t=\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)$ and $dt=-\frac{1}{x^2+x}dx$

$$-\int t dt=-\frac{t^2}{2}+\mathcal C=\boxed{\color{blue}{-\frac 1 2(\ln(x)-\ln(x+1))^2+\mathcal C}}$$

Comment: Very nice! $\quad$

Comment: brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that the numerator is
$$
\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
so you could try
$$
t=1+\frac{1}{x}
$$
that gives
$$
x=\frac{1}{t-1}
$$
so that
$$
x^2+x=\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}+\frac{1}{t-1}=\frac{t}{(t-1)^2}
$$
and
$$
dx=-\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}\,dt
$$
so the integral becomes
$$
\int(\ln t)\frac{(t-1)^2}{t}\frac{-1}{(t-1)^2}\,dt=-\int\frac{\ln t}{t}\,dt
$$
that should be easy.

Comment: @walker427 Maybe not the fastest, but quite safe. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\int \left(\frac{\log(x+1)-\log(x)}{x(x+1)}\right)\,dx&=\int \left(\frac1x-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)\left(\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=-\int \left(\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right)\left(\frac{d\left(\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right)}{dx}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac12 \left(\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right)^2+C
\end{align}$$